# Joomla fields : change dynamically the readonly property

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

in Joomla component forms :

is there a way to dynamically change the form field property : "readonly" ?

example :

```
if( _condition_ )
   $this->form->getInput('Name')->readonly = true;
```

Answer (score 6):

From what I saw in the API, you basically can change it.

I see it like this:

When you call `$this->form->getInput('Name')` you are inside JFormField object (actually inside an class which interits JFormField, which is abstract - inherited by JFormFieldText for example), calling the method `getInput()`.

This method, `getInput()`,  gets its parameters `$element` ( SimpleXMLElement object of the  XML element that describes the form field.) from what I can see directly from the XML you defined and it returns just a string (actual HTML), so setting and non existing property obviously won't work.

But JForm has a nice method called setFieldAttribute(), see signature below:

```
 /**
 * Method to set an attribute value for a field XML element.
 *
 * @param   string  $name       The name of the form field for which to set the attribute value.
 * @param   string  $attribute  The name of the attribute for which to set a value.
 * @param   mixed   $value      The value to set for the attribute.
 * @param   string  $group      The optional dot-separated form group path on which to find the field.
 *
 * @return  boolean  True on success.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function setFieldAttribute($name, $attribute, $value, $group = null)
```

So your code can look like:

```
if( _condition_ ) 
{
    $this->form->setFieldAttribute('Name', 'readonly', 'true', $group = null);
    echo $this->form->getInput('name');
}
```

Hope this helps.